# Jasig CAS - How to fetch different roles when accessing different applications?

Tags: spring, authentication, cas, jasig

Whenever a change applications, I need CAS to fetch a new set of roles from the server (the set of roles for that specific application). Is there a way to do so?

As it is today, it gets the roles for the first application (lets name it A) and when I access the application B I can only see the roles for application A, which gives me a 403 (access denied) error code.

Ex:

Product A has the roles: ADMIN, MANAGER and STAFF.

Product B has the roles: ADMIN, BACKOFFICE, FRONTOFFICE.

When I access Product A first CAS detects that the user is accessing int through Product A and puts its three roles in session and everything goes fine for Product A.

After that I access product B and CAS sees that I have a valid ticket and grants me access to Product B, but instead of fetching roles again for product B (ADMIN, BACKOFFICE and FRONTOFFICE), it keeps the roles from Produca A (ADMIN, MANAGER, STAFF).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand clearly your need. Though, you can manage attributes returned by the CAS server to the different applications and therefore compute appropriate roles by following this documentation : https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Attributes.

Comment: I edited the question adding more details. It would be possible to get every role for every application when we first sign in but that's not what we want.

Comment: User attributes are retrieved once, at CAS login. If you want to get additionnal roles in your web application, I recommend you get them from your web application (this way, CAS = authentication, webapp = authorization)